# Restricted resource access when auto run EXE over HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry key

Tags: windows, registry, console-application, regedit

I have an EXE file, and i whant to launch it every windows start for all users.
am adding a registry key on : 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
My EXE works fine, but it can't access to any other file (.txt) even the required file is in the same location.
it seems like an access denied. why?

My Exe is a .NET application (C# console application) reading a text file content.

Comment: Always use full path names for files, c:\foo\bar\baz.txt.  Just baz.txt will not work, the Environment.CurrentDirectory is not set where you hope it is.  Use AppData, if necessary use Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) to know where your EXE was installed.

Comment: this works for me. Thank's @HansPassant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from @HansPassant :

Always use full path names for files, `c:\foo\bar\baz.txt`. Just baz.txt will not work, the Environment.CurrentDirectory is not set where you hope it is. Use AppData, if necessary use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` to know where your EXE was installed.